# lua - How to perform transitions in sequence

Tags: animation, lua, coronasdk

i'm trying to move an object along the points of a complex curved path with a constant velocity using transitions.
I have two tables to keep the coordinates of the points and another table with the respective time intervals for travelling each linear segment at the same speed (despite they have different lengths).

Assuming the firts and last values of the "timeTable" are 0, i tried with something similar to this:

```
local i = 1
local function Move()
        transition.to(player, {time=timeTable[i+1], x=TableX[i+1], y=TableY[i+1]})
        i=i+1
end 
timer.performWithDelay( timeTable[i], Move, 0 )
```

It doesn't work although it no error is given.
Thanks in advance for your helpenter code here

Comment: If you want constant velocity when you don't need table with time intervals and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would work

```
local timeTable = {1,     3,   4,   1}
local TableX    = {100, 400, 400, 500}
local TableY    = {100, 100, 500, 500}

local i = 0

local function onCompleteMove()
   i = i + 1
   if timeTable[i] then
      transition.to(player, {
         time=timeTable[i], 
         x=TableX[i], 
         y=TableY[i], 
         onComplete=onCompleteMove
      })
   end
end

onCompleteMove()  -- start moving to first point
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

- [Tutorial: Moving objects along a path](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/07/tutorial-moving-objects-along-a-path/)
- [Tutorial: Working with curved paths](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/09/09/tutorial-working-with-curved-paths/)

Method for chain of transition for the same object

```
local function chainOfTransitions(object, params, ...)
   if params then
        function params.onComplete() 
            chainOfTransitions(object, unpack(arg)) 
        end

        transition.to(object, params)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you!
I accomplished the goal by doing so:

```
local segmentTransition
local delta = 1
local function onCompleteMove()
    i = i + delta
    if timeTable[i] then
        segmentTransition = transition.to(player2, {
            time=timeTable[i],
            x=tableX[i+delta],
            y=tableY[i+delta],
            onComplete=onCompleteMove
        })
    end
end

onCompleteMove()  -- start moving
```